Do I need PyTorch on each Spark node, or just the master for running examples?
Do I need to install PyTorch on each node of an Apache Spark cluster, or is it sufficient to install it only on the master node for executing examples smoothly?
I attempted to execute a PyTorch example on an Apache Spark cluster without installing PyTorch on all nodes, expecting that installation on the master node alone would suffice for seamless execution.
